# Error In Function Name

Tags: vba, excel

I get an error when trying to use the below function. The strange part is that the error occurs in the name

Code:

```
Function DATECHECK(rng As Range, date_time As Date) As Boolean

    For Row = 1 To rng.Rows.Count

    'Stuff'
    Next Row

 End Function
```

Syntax:

```
DateCheck(Sheet2!A2:B561, Sheet1!A2)
```

Error:

```
#NAME
#NAME(Sheet2!A2:B561, Sheet1!A2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure the function is in a public module; not a private worksheet code sheet.
2. DateCheck should return something. Add `DateCheck = 1` before End Function.
3. You cannot manipulate values of other cells with a worksheet UDF. You decided that showing the relevant code wasn't important; it was important.
4. In your function's context, `Row` is a variable. You need to declare it as a long (e.g. `dim row as long`) if you are using `Option Explicit`.

Comment: I thought it might be a naming error. However, if a do the following:

`Public Function DATECHECK(rng As Range, date_time As Date) As Boolean
    Dim Row As Integer
    
    For Row = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    
        DATECHECK = True
        
    Next Row
    
    DATECHECK = True
End Function`

it still doesn't work

Comment: Works fine for me when pasted into a module. Do you have a sheet1 and sheet2? Put a stop on the var declarations and step through with F8.

Comment: Ok yea so it has something to do with the sheet. I created a new one and it worked fine.